# Ruby threads and variable

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

Why the result is not from 1 to 10, but 10s only?

```
require 'thread'

def run(i)
  puts i
end

while true
  for i in 0..10
    Thread.new{ run(i)}
  end
  sleep(100)
end
```

Result:

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Why loop? I am running while loop, because later I want to iterate through the DB table all the time and echo any records that are retrieved from the DB.

Comment: Actually I ran your code on my machine and got some `3`s and some `10`s.

Comment: @DavidGrayson it is unpredictable what you will get here. You don't have guarantee for Thread context switching. So you could get many variants of result depending on the Moon phase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The block that is passed to `Thread.new` may actually begin at some point in the future, and by that time the value of `i` may have changed. In your case, they all have incremented up to `10` prior to when all the threads actually run.

To fix this, use the form of [`Thread.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html#method-c-new) that accepts a parameter, in addition to the block:

```
require 'thread'

def run(i)
  puts i
end

while true
  for i in 0..10
    Thread.new(i) { |j| run(j) }
  end
  sleep(100)
end
```

This sets the block variable `j` to the value of `i` at the time `new` was called.

Comment: Great! So now the second part :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708758/how-to-asynchronously-collect-results-from-new-threads-created-in-real-time-in-r

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have created 11 threads that are all trying to access the same variable `i` which was defined by the main thread of your program.  One trick to avoid that is to call `Thread.new` inside a method; then the variable `i` that the thread has access to is just the particular `i` that was passed to the method, and it is not shared with other threads.  This takes advantage of a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

```
require 'thread'

def run(i)
  puts i
end

def start_thread(i)
  Thread.new { run i }
end

for i in 0..10
  start_thread i
  sleep 0.1
end
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

(I added the `sleep` just to guarantee that the threads run in numerical order so we can have tidy output, but you could take it out and still have a valid program where each thread gets the correct argument.)

Answer (score 2):

@DavidGrayson is right.

You can see here a side effect in `for loop`. In your case `i` variable scope is whole your file. While you are expecting only a block in your `for loop` as a scope. Actually this is wrong approach in idiomatic Ruby. Ruby gives you iterators for this job.

```
(1..10).each do |i|
   Thread.new{ run(i)}
end
```

In this case scope of variable `i` will be isolated in block scope what means for each iteration you will get new local (for this block) variable `i`.