# How to asynchronously collect results from new threads created in real time in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, process, thread-safety, spawn

I would like to continously check the table in the DB for the commands to run.
Some commands might take 4minutes to complete, some 10 seconds.

Hence I would like to run them in threads. So every record creates new thread, and after thread is created, record gets removed.

Because the DB lookup + Thread creation will run in an endless loop, how do I get the 'response' from the Thread (thread will issue shell command and get response code which I would like to read) ?

I thought about creating two Threads with endless loop each:
- first for DB lookups + creating new threads
- second for ...somehow reading the threads results and acting upon each response

Or maybe I should use fork, or os spawn a new process?

Comment: Can you have each command thread take the response code and store it back to the DB, as part of the same record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have each thread push its results onto a Queue, then your main thread can read from the Queue.  Reading from a Queue is a blocking operation by default, so if there are no results, your code will block and wait on the read.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html

Here is an example:

```
require 'thread'

jobs = Queue.new
results = Queue.new

thread_pool = []
pool_size = 5

(1..pool_size).each do |i|
  thread_pool << Thread.new do 
    loop do 
      job = jobs.shift #blocks waiting for a task
      break if job == "!NO-MORE-JOBS!"

      #Otherwise, do job...
      puts "#{i}...."
      sleep rand(1..5) #Simulate the time it takes to do a job
      results << "thread#{i} finished #{job}"  #Push some result from the job onto the Queue
      #Go back and get another task from the Queue
    end
  end
end


#All threads are now blocking waiting for a job...
puts 'db_stuff'
db_stuff = [
  'job1', 
  'job2', 
  'job3', 
  'job4', 
  'job5',
  'job6',
  'job7',
]

db_stuff.each do |job|
  jobs << job
end

#Threads are now attacking the Queue like hungry dogs.

pool_size.times do
  jobs << "!NO-MORE-JOBS!"
end

result_count = 0

loop do
  result = results.shift
  puts "result: #{result}"
  result_count +=1
  break if result_count == 7
end
```

Comment: When talking about queues - `push` and `pop` are conventionally used, rather than `<<` and `shift`

Comment: great. this works perfectly. just one more question. sometimes threads get killed how do I recreate a new threads to fill up the pool?